# Returning data from dynamic (AJAX) loaded Bootstrap Modal

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap modal's in a Codeigniter application as a popup WYSIWYG text-editor. Everything in regards to loading content, and the modal, works fine. I can even save the content when the modal is open via AJAX.

But what I am trying to accomplish is when I hit the "Save" button in my modal... I want to return the value — `$('#wysiwyg').val()` — to the page that opened the modal.

**Link triggering the modal**

```
<a href="/ajax/modals/wysiwyg" class="btn ajax-modal">Write Text</a>
```

**JavaScript loading modal** - Modified source from https://gist.github.com/drewjoh/1688900

```
$('.ajax-modal').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var modal = $('#ajax-modal');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    if(url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
        $(url).modal('open');
    } else {
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            modal.html(data);
            modal.modal();
        }).success(function() { 
            /* boom. loaded. */ 
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML modal wrapper**

```
<div id="ajax-modal" class="modal hide fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

**HTML modal body/contents**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Text Editor</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

    <textarea class="input-block-level" id="wysiwyg" rows="9">Write something...</textarea>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button id="submit-modal" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var modal = $('#ajax-modal');

// Filter clicks within the modal to those on the save button (#submit-modal)
modal.on('click', '#submit-modal', function(e) {

    // Find the wysiwyg within the modal        
    var wysiwyg = $('#wysiwyg', modal);

    // Now do what you want with wysiwyg.val();
    if (wysiwyg.length) $('#my_info_div').html(wysiwyg.val());
});
```

Comment: Is this going in my modal? or on the page that triggered the modal?

Comment: This goes on the page that hosts the #ajax-modal container (so the page that triggered the modal).

Answer (score 2):

I think I get what you are asking for...There are a few ways you can do this.  If you want to create a more separated approach you could use a pub/sub framework like Amplify.  The simplest approach would be to create a reference to the element you want to populate prior to creating the click event.  Like so:

```
var controlToPopulate = $("#controlToPopulateId");
$('.ajax-modal').click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

var modal = $('#ajax-modal');
var url = $(this).attr('href');

if(url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
    $(url).modal('open');
} else {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        modal.html(data);
        modal.modal();
    }).success(function() { 
        /* boom. loaded. */
        modal.find('#submit-modal').click(function() {
           controlToPopulate.val(modal.find('#wysiwyg').val());
       });
    });
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did work, but I went with another answer because it integrated better with some of my other code.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote `if(url.indexOf('#') == 0)`, did you mean `if(url.indexOf('#') == -1)`? `indexOf('#')` returns `-1` if `#` does not appear in the string.

Comment: No I wrote it correct. The reason I am checking for `0` is because if the modal content is inline and not being called via a URL, then it should load the modal the default way (as in all the Bootstrap examples show).